# Azure VM disk with public access

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

Why the recommended step for the "Azure VM disk with public access" points to enabling private access link with private endpoint instead of just disabling the public access on the VM disk.
I tried manually disabling the public access on I did not see any impact. If disabling the public access would work then  I am thinking of applying
`# Connect to Azure
Connect-AzAccount

```
# Get all VM disks with public access enabled

$disks = Get-AzDisk | Where-Object { $_.DiskState -eq 'Attached' -and $_.DiskSizeGB -gt 0 -and $\_.PublicAccess -eq 'Enabled' }

# Disable public access for each disk

foreach ($disk in $disks) {
Write-Host "Disabling public access for disk $($disk.Name)..."

    # Update the disk with public access disabled
    $disk | Set-AzDiskAccess -Access Read -DisallowPublicAccess
    Write-Host "Public access disabled for disk $($disk.Name)."

}
```

Trying to figure out best and easiest way to stay compliant.

Comment: At the very least you should probably link to the doc that tells you to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enabling `Private Endpoint with Private Access Link` for `Azure VM` disks will provide more security and control over accessing the disk, but it does not prevent access from other `Azure resources` or within the `Azure Virtual Network`.

If you disable the public access on the `Azure VM` disk will restrict access from the public internet and does not provide the same level of isolation and control as using `Private Endpoint and Private Access Link`.

The recommendation to use `Private Endpoint` with `Private Access Link` for `Azure VM` disks with public access aims to provide a high secure solution that aligns with best practices for network security.

Here is the updated script to disable public access on all VM disks that have public access enabled.

```
    #Get all VM disks with public access enabled
    $disks = Get-AzDisk | Where-Object { $_.DiskState -eq 'Attached' -and $_.DiskSizeGB -gt 0 -and $_.PublicAccess -eq 'Enabled' }
    
    #Disable public access for each disk
    foreach ($disk in $disks) {
        Write-Host "Disabling public access for disk $($disk.Name)..."
        
        # Update the disk with public access disabled
        $disk | New-AzDiskUpdateConfig -PublicNetworkAccess "Disabled" -NetworkAccessPolicy "AllowPrivate"
        Write-Host "Public access disabled for disk $($disk.Name)."
    }
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: I was able to figure out the code part. When it did not disable from portal and I have to use deny all on networkpolicy. Our client has less block on network to dedicate bunch of storage for private EP. but thanks for clarifying the need of private ep